# Resizing table range error "Method 'Range' of Object '_Global' failed"

Tags: excel, vba, datatable, resize, listobject

I have code which attempts to reference a table and resize it.

It first checks to see if the table has filters applied and removes them.

I will skip the code preceding the key bits. I declared the variables which you can't see in this code, but the relevant declarations are contained below. Also tried with Option Explicit both declared and then not declared.

```vb
Dim ExcelTool As Workbook: Set ExcelTool = Workbooks.Open(ExcelTool_Template_Path1 & 
ExcelTool_Template_Name1, ReadOnly:=True)
Dim ExcelToolRates As Worksheet: Set ExcelToolRates = ExcelTool.Worksheets("Rates")
Dim RatesTable As ListObject: Set RatesTable = ExcelToolRates.ListObjects("Table1")
If RatesTable.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then
    RatesTable.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End If

ExcelToolRates.Activate
RatesTable.Resize Range(3)
```

Everything else works including the filter removal using the object variable "RatesTable".

When it comes to resizing it gives the error

> "Method 'Range' of Object '_Global' failed"

"Table1" was the default table name when I converted the range to a table and it is in this workbook.

The code is run from a different workbook in the same instance of Excel. I tried making the workbook which contains the referenced table active and using this line instead but same error:

```vb
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Rates").ListObjects("Table1").Resize Range(3)
```

Following advice from Chris I tried

```vb
RatesTable.Resize RatesTable.DatabodyRange.Resize(3)
```

That produces the following error:

[image]

Comment: In the line `RatesTable.Resize Range(3)` what do you expect `Range(3)` to do?

Comment: Hi Chris, I thought it would resize the table to 3 rows so I can retain the header and a couple of rows before pasting in new data (which may or may not be fewer rows than the previous dataset hence getting rid of most of the old data rows for good measure). Several articles found via Google suggested that's what I needed to do, but I may be being stupid...

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to listobject.resize needs to be a range object that refers to the new table data range.

Something like

```
RatesTable.Resize RatesTable.DatabodyRange.Resize(3)
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the swift response and help. I tried you line of code but it returned the error which I added to my question (I couldn't figure out how to add the error picture to this comment). Any ideas? Thank you!